# Scrape the Stack Overflow user data

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import csv

url='https://stackoverflow.com/users'
response= requests.get(url)
html=response.content

soup= BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')

divs= soup.find_all("div", class_='container')

with open('stackdata.csv', 'a') as csv_file:
    writer=csv.writer(csv_file)
    for div in divs:
        print(div.text)
        name_box=soup.find('div', attrs={'class': 'user-details'})
        name=name_box.text
        print(name)
        writer.writerow([name])
```

When I use div.text it prints all the data but when I want to write those data in a csv file it goes only one upper data.

Comment: If you print it, you will get only one result. This is what the csv file is getting update with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is how you wanted your scraper behaves. Run it and find a csv file with data filled in.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import csv

response = requests.get('https://stackoverflow.com/users').text
soup = BeautifulSoup(response, 'lxml')
for items in soup.select('.user-details'):
    name = items.select("a")[0].text
    location = items.select(".user-location")[0].text
    reputation = items.select(".reputation-score")[0].text
    print(name,location,reputation)

    with open('stackdata.csv','a',newline='') as csv_file:
        writer = csv.writer(csv_file)
        writer.writerow([name,location,reputation])
```

Comment: All details are  comes in one single column, how to strip into three different columns.

Comment: See the edited code. You will have each fields in individual columns now.

Comment: But when i choose the next page for new user it's output is remain same?

Comment: You should open a new thread mentioning the problem you encounter now. All the problems can't be solved in a single thread. Thanks.